# Can't resize existing partition with gparted

Tags: gparted, partitioning, ext4, unallocated

I'm trying to resize my ext4 partition where my ubuntu (elementary os) is installed on.
I started a ubuntu live cd and opened gparted, see screenshot
[image]

There is no way to allocate the free space for sda4 or sda5. What's the reason?
Extending sda3 is possible..

Thanks in advance!

//edit.  sorry forget to mention that the unallocated partition was a windows install and I had a dualboot option.

Comment: Are you trying to add the unallocated partition's free space to existing non-adjacent sda4 partition?

Comment: Yep :) That was my intention, didn't know this wasn't possible and had no visual feedback why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to extend a partition, you need free space adjacent to it.

In your case you would have to move `/dev/sda3`. This can take a very long time.

Extend the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`) to include the free space.

Finally extend `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know it isn't possible when the partitions are non-adjacent (no hint or anything, of course I didn't read the manual). Now I get it. Would be easier for GUI-users (newbees) to make it possible to use unallocated space on non-adjacent partitions in one step on the frontend (and doing the three steps in the background)